# The kernel 'Python 3.7.3 64-bit' died. View Jupyter log for further details

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a project, every time the execution cycle reaches the cell:

```
#Split data.
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.1, random_state = 45)
print(X_train.shape, Y_train.shape)
```

the kernel dies. I have tried uninstalling ipython, jupyter, ipykernel and reinstalling all of them and still no luck. On a different PC, the code runs completely fine without the error.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated, desperate for answers have been searching for hours now.

The error in the Jupyter log is:

```
Error: Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
at t.KernelShellFutureHandler.dispose (/home/vscode/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801/out/extension.js:2:1204175)
at /home/vscode/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801/out/extension.js:2:1223227
at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
at v._clearKernelState (/home/vscode/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801/out/extension.js:2:1223212)
at v.dispose (/home/vscode/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801/out/extension.js:2:1216694)
at /home/vscode/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801/out/extension.js:2:533674
at t.swallowExceptions (/home/vscode/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801/out/extension.js:2:913059)
at dispose (/home/vscode/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801/out/extension.js:2:533652)
at t.RawSession.dispose (/home/vscode/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.3.1000901801/out/extension.js:2:537330)
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Comment: Most commonly, this is caused by running out of memory. Are you running out of memory?

Comment: Just checked task manager, yeah its using 100% memory, ive reduced size of dataset and its fine, now im getting an error saying 'Read less bytes than requested'